# Owl carousel is getting display none

Tags: owl-carousel

I have used owl-carousel but it's not working. When I inspect the browser found .owl-carousel div shows display:none. Quickly it's working and changes to display none.
I used the carousel from code-pen https://codepen.io/niloydeysarkar/pen/MxZdeE

I copied the code same as given. I checked the both owl.carousel.min.css and owl.theme.default.min.css and in head section bootstrap 4 css also.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
```

Also the jquery and the owl.carousel.min.js and bootstrap.min.js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/function.js"></script>
```

All css, js code I just copied and pasted.
Should I include the full code I pasted?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with these

### CSS Plugins

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

### jQuery and JS

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/function.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4, animate css and bootstrap 4 js also included from previously. I didn't mention this.